# Access is denied System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

**please help me anyone to solve my Erorr when login to my admin account in site....**

---

Access is denied
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll from the location specified in the registry. Verify that the Local Database Runtime feature of SQL Server Express is properly installed.)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +830
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +329
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +682
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +89
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +217
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user) +43
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe() +41
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode() +21
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +57
   System.Data.Linq.Table`1.GetEnumerator() +41
   System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() +9
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +369
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   bicycle.DbClass.GetUserID(String UserName, String PassWord) in c:\Users\Emperor.Emperor-PC\Desktop\New folder (3)\Bikes\DbClass1.cs:193
   bicycle.Cart.LogInControl.aaddD_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Emperor.Emperor-PC\Desktop\New folder (3)\Bikes\User\LogInControl.ascx.cs:20
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9692626
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3562

Comment: Did you read the error?  **SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll from the location specified in the registry. Verify that the Local Database Runtime feature of SQL Server Express is properly installed.)**

Comment: Try googling on that error message and see what you get.

Comment: There are lot of posts about this error. The answers are about SqlServer Configuration, is named pipe enabled ? is tcpip enabled ? is your firewall not blocking your request ?

Comment: I need to help coz server support  not I did not know why and I did not know I have done everything

Comment: in localhost all things is done but online no when log in to admin accuont

Answer (score 0):

if your on windows, create a .udl file and test your DB connection string
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e(v=vs.71).aspx)

1. create a text file and rename the extension to .udl
2. double click the file and enter your DB connection information
3. verify that you can connect to the database
4. verify that your application is using the same connection string

Comment: This is not my problem. The problem is that I can not access my account on the site on the server. I am a local Host everything works well

Comment: I was suggesting this as a means to troubleshoot the connection that would give you a more accurate error message